# How to use thread in c++ win 32

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to use thread in C ++ like c # then what to do, I tried to do it but failed, hope the helping (Why can't I post, someone edit the content for me)

> Here is my c # code

```
Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[100];

public class Users
{
    public ListView listView1;
    public string sName;
    public string sName2;

    public void Run()
    {
        listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = sName;
        listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = sName2;

        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i += 1;
            listView1.Items[0].SubItems[3].Text = i.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    Users user = new Users();
    user.listView1 = listView1;
    user.sName = "avan";
    user.sName2 = "strong";

    int iThread = 1;
    threadsArray[iThread] = new Thread(user.Run);
    threadsArray[iThread].IsBackground = true;
    threadsArray[iThread].Start();
}
```

---

This is the C++ code which I tried:

```
//cMain.h
#pragma once
#include "wx\/wx.h"
#include <wx/listctrl.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <thread>

using std::string;
class cMain : public wxFrame
{ 
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();

public:

    wxListView *Listview1;
    string sName;
    string sName2;

    void Run();
};

//cMain.cpp
#include "cMain.h"

cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Form 1", wxPoint(30,30), wxSize(800,600))
{
    Listview1 = new wxListView(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0, 100), wxSize(300, 300));

    Listview1->AppendColumn("NO", wxLIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 40);
    Listview1->InsertItem(0, "");

    Listview1->AppendColumn("NAME", wxLIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 80);
    Listview1->InsertItem(1, "");

    Listview1->AppendColumn("NAME2", wxLIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 80);
    Listview1->InsertItem(2, "");

    Listview1->AppendColumn("NUMBER", wxLIST_FORMAT_RIGHT, 80);
    Listview1->InsertItem(3, "");

    cMain cmain;
    cmain.sName = "avan";
    cmain.sName2 = "strong";

    std::thread task(cmain.Run, NULL);
    task.join();

}


void cMain::Run()
{

    Listview1->SetItem(0, 1, sName);
    Listview1->SetItem(0, 2, sName);

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i += 1;
        Listview1->SetItem(0, 2, std::to_string(i));
        Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the wrong ones (like the C language tag instead of C++).

Comment: As for your problem, the key to be able to successfully translate between different languages (programming, spoken or written) is to be fluent in *both* languages. And in programming, it's often better to generalize the actual algorithm used in the program, and then reimplement it in the new language. A straight literal translation will almost always result in rather bad code.

Comment: Your options are, from lowest to highest level: `1` Native OS threads (`CreateThread`). `2` The CRT's wrappers (`_beginthreadex`). `3` C++' language level threads (`std::thread`). On top of that you can use C++' higher level abstractions, like `std::async` and/or C++20 coroutines. All options are documented in excruciating detail, with loads of resources readily available online.

Comment: C ++ is there a way to do it like c #, I want to assign listview but give an error, can you give me an example that can solve this problem

Comment: Please add the C++ code you tried to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You define the object of the constructor in the constructor of the
  cMain class, which will call the constructor repeatedly.
- When creating the thread run, you passed a NULL parameter. I didn't
  see the declaration of this parameter in the run function. If you
  don't need it, please delete it.

I removed some irrelevant code and created a minimal code example, Hope to help you.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Users
{
public:
    string sName;
    string sName2;

    static void Run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i += 1;
            Sleep(200);
        }
    }

};

class cMain
{
public:
    cMain();  

public:
    string sName;
    string sName2;

};

cMain::cMain()
{ 
    Users *user = new Users();
    user->sName = "avan";
    user->sName2 = "strong";

    std::thread task(user->Run);
    task.join();
    delete user;
}


int main()
{
    cMain cmain;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Strive Sun - MSFT, I did

Comment: @Baranh If the answer useful to you, please feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.

Comment: @Baranh [How do I accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)